# Write RSpec tests for APIs with apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

I added the apartment gem to my project, and everything is working well in my development, and I haven't any problem.
Right now, I want to update my RSpec tests with tenant subdomains.
I added:
`Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain.excluded_subdomains = ['www']`
Also, for RSpec, I added:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    # Clean all tables to start
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
    # Use transactions for tests
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    # Truncating doesn't drop schemas, ensure we're clean here, app *may not* exist
    Apartment::Tenant.drop('test_app') rescue nil
    # Create the default tenant for our tests
    Apartment::Tenant.create('test_app')
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    # Start transaction for this test
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    # Switch into the default tenant
    Apartment::Tenant.switch! 'test_app'
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    # Reset tentant back to `public`
    Apartment::Tenant.reset
    # Rollback transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

My Test is:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::AccountsController, type: :request do
  describe '.create' do
    context 'valid requests' do
      it 'creates accounts' do
        # Require data
        user   = create(:user)
        project   = create(:project, user: user)

        attributes = {
          account: FactoryBot.attributes_for(:account_params),
        }

        # Request
        sign_in(user)

        post "/en/api/v1/projects/#{project.id}/accounts",
             headers: auth_header,
             params: attributes

        # Expects
        # MY TESTS ARE HERE
      end
    end
  end
end
```

right now, I haven't any subdomain as default, so If I update the host like this `host! "test_app.example.com"` and call my API like this:
`post "/en/api/v1/projects/#{project.id}/accounts"` I'm getting this error `*** URI::InvalidURIError Exception: the scheme http does not accept registry part: test_app.example.com (or bad hostname?)`
and if I send the request like this: `post "en/api/v1/projects/#{project.id}/accounts"` I'll get this error: `*** URI::InvalidURIError Exception: bad URI(is not URI?): "http://test_app.example.com:80en/api/v1/projects/1/accounts"`

Does anybody know how I can fix this issue and send my request to the correct subdomain? (this API working well in my development)